# macOS Sonoma 14.4 breaks moving the "zoomed in" area while zoomed in

Tags: macos, display, accessibility, zoom

As of at least macOS Sonoma v14.4, part of the system accessibility feature of being able to zoom in on a portion of your screen, seems to be broken. Specifically it broke the ability to move the zoomed-in area around so you can see other parts of the screen. This seems to be broken on Intel-based Macs. Not sure if Apple silicon Macs have the same problem. If I use the default panning mode, "Zoomed image moves: When Pointer Reaches Edge", I can't move the zoomed-in area at all. If I use either of the other two options, "Continuously with Pointer" or "To Keep Pointer Centered", I'm immediately kicked out of zoomed-in mode as soon as I move my mouse.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sonoma 14.4 does seem to have introduced all kinds of bugs, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for now, until Apple hopefully fixes this in a future update, is to disable the "Zoom each display independently" toggle in System Settings > Accessibility > Zoom > Advanced.

NB: I didn't even have any extra displays attached; I was simply using my Intel-based MBP's built-in screen, but disabling the above toggle still fixed it for me.